# Create index on links of graph database

Tags: indexing, orientdb

Is there any way to create index on links of graph database (**orientDB**) like the below example.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX <index_name> ON <link_name> (<link_property>) DICTIONARY
```

Comment: Hi, Stephen can you help with the above issue. @stephenmallette

Comment: sorry - no -  i don't know the specifics of orientdb when it comes to indexing. i just know that TinkerPop is not responsible for those capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

In according to the documentation to create an index you have to specify a class name.
For more info: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Index.html

Regards

Comment: So, the indexes can only be created on classes not on links.

Comment: You can simply create an index or an index on a property

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)